# Pylab: Bounding box despite frameon=False

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

When I set the visibility of the axis to false, the axis are replaced by a bounding box. Please would someone be able to help me to remove the bounding frame.

```
import pylab

x=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
y=[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8]


pylab.figure(num=1,frameon=False)
circle = pylab.Circle((0, 0), 1.025, color="black", fill=None)
ax = pylab.subplot(111, aspect=1)
ax.add_artist(circle)
ax.scatter(x,y,s=30, c='red', marker='o', edgecolor='red')
pylab.xlim([-1.1,1.1])
pylab.ylim([-1.1,1.1])
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
pylab.title("Plot")
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ax.axison=False`, as you noticed axes are "replaced" by the bounding box, but it looks like it has nothing to do with the figure. In IPython I just browsed through the properties of `ax` and found the property `axison`. Turned it to `false` and it worked for me